# Can the Google Map API be used with an external map file ?

Tags: api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

If the detail level of the area I want to display in my application is not good enough (like large private properties such has harbours or airports), can I replace the original Google Map with own data ? Using with Google Map enterprise/business version.

Thanks
Sven

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a [custom map type](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes#CustomMapTypes), that uses your tiles when the zoom is greater than that supported by Google Maps tiles natively.